# Streamlit Live Updating Charts across multiple tabs arranged in columns

Tags: python, dashboard, streamlit

I am trying to build a complex dashboard in Python using Streamlit. The source of the data is going to a mixture of live streams out of a socket/message-broker queue, static data, DB queries and REST calls. The aim of this question is to understand how I structure the streamlit components so that data ends up in the right place, and updates accordingly. Due to the complexity I cannot reasonably produce a runnable example - but I will aim to explain as clearly as I can.

```py
import streamlit as st
import threading
import queue
import panda as pd

class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self,q: Queue) -> None:
        self.q = q
    
    def run(self,):
        # receive from either socket of message broker, then put
        # in queue for loop in main to process
        pass

class DataStore:
    
    def __init__(self,name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.data = {}
        self.df1 = pd.DataFrame()
        self.df2 = pd.DataFrame()

    def update(self,d: dict):
        self.data.update(d)
        # maybe some further updates to the dfs if needed
        

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    q = queue.Queue()
    
    consumer = Consumer(q=q)
    consumer.start()
    
    # Dummy for explanation
    names = ['foo','bar','baz','dog','cat','mouse']
    
    # This seems to be usually necessary
    placeholder = st.empty()
    
    # Now i need to have multiple columns in multiple tabs
    # Each tab will have 1 DataStore object, but multiple components
    # will read out of that data store.
    
    # Do I put columns in here at this stage?
    combs = [(DataStore(name),t) for name,t in zip(names,st.tabs(names))]
    # combs = [(DataStore(name),t,cols) for name,t,cols in zip(names,st.tabs(names),st.columns(2))]
    
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        # data will have a name so I can filter on that
        cur_data,cur_tab = list(filter(lambda x: x[0].name==data['name'],combs))[0]
        
        # Here is where I get stuck
        
        with cur_comb:
            
            # WHAT NOW? 
            col1,col2 = st.columns(2)
            with col1:
                st.line_chart(cur_data.df1)
            with col2:
                st.line_chart(cur_data.df2)
```

This question is not about the specifics of what is wrong with this code, it is more aimed at 'what are the best practices surrounding multi-tabbed, mult-columned, live-updating streamlit graph components. Should I be using the streamlit context manager approach? or `st.write`? Where should I create the columns? In the infinite loop or prior?

Thank you for your help in advance.

I have attempted both angles, context manager and st.write - but the approach feels clunky. I hope there are some more out the box solutions to this - or certainly best practices.